# "<i>" interrupting correct node selection

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to select a table field with the following structure:

```
<td class='postac'>proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu <I>i.v.</I>
                    1,5 g
                1 fiol. typu Monovial
</td>
```

After using xpath expression `sel.xpath("//table[@class='table-postaci']/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()").extract()` I get two values instead of one:

```
u'proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu ',
                u'\r\n                            1,5 g\r\n                        1 fiol. typu Monovial\r\n        '
```

Is it some clean xpath method to get this "td" field as a single value? I know I could get the field with `//table[@class='table-postaci']/tbody/tr/td[2]` and then strip the tags in the scrapy pipeline. However, I'm looking for some simplier solution. Thank you

Comment: Are these all ASCII characters as you showed, or are some Latin-x or UTF-8? I'm wondering if scrapy's processor is not aware of the encoding you're using, and is choking when it comes across as an invalid character (for UTF-8 in particular). only I have experience with Selenium and Xpaths (using only ASCII text), so I probably can't help any more than that with Middle-/Eastern-European languages and non-ASCII text. Otherwise, I _would_ expect text() to return a single string. Is extract() supposed to do anything special with what xpath() has returned? Could it be the one who is splitting it?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I don't think it's a problem with encoding cause I had succesfully scraped utf-8 endcoded data. And in this example there are just basic characters. Maybe the source code of the page would be useful: [link](bazalekow.mp.pl/leki/item.html?id=19607&item_id=51621) Looks like <I> tag is a problem here and scrapy reads text values before and after as two seperate elements. The extract method should just return the textual value of the selected node.

Comment: I don't see anything odd there. Just out of curiosity, does scrapy behave any differently if you change them to lower case i's (`<i>...</i>`)? If so, that's a scrapy bug. Is there any chance that your HTML line (whatever script outputs it) has some odd end-of-line marker (not `\r\n` like the other lines)? Does this happen on lines where there is text after the `</I>`?

Comment: @PhilPerry Seems that it was a problem with xpath expresion. I should use //text() instead of /text(), which selelcted only first node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over each table row `tr` and for each row join all text node descendants of the 2nd `td` cell:

```
In [13]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [14]: selector = Selector(text="""<table class='table-postaci'>
   ....:        <thead><th>Nazwa preparatu</th><th>Postać i dawka</th><th>Producent</th><th>Cena 100%</th>
   ....:                        <th>Odpłatność po refundacji</th>
   ....:        </thead>
   ....:        <tbody>
   ....: 
   ....:                        <tr>
   ....:                <td class='postac'>Zinacef </td>
   ....:                <td class='postac'>proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu <I>i.v.</I>
   ....:                             1,5 g
   ....:                         1 fiol. typu Monovial
   ....:         </td>
   ....:                <td>GlaxoSmithKline – Wielka Brytania</td>
   ....:                <td class='cena'> b/d </td>
   ....:                                <td>
   ....:                                </td>
   ....:                </tr>
   ....:                        <tr>
   ....:                <td class='postac'>Zinacef </td>
   ....:                <td class='postac'>proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu <I>i.v.</I>
   ....:                             750 mg
   ....:                         1 fiol. typu Monovial
   ....:         </td>
   ....:                <td>GlaxoSmithKline – Wielka Brytania</td>
   ....:                <td class='cena'> b/d </td>
   ....:                                <td>
   ....:                                </td>
   ....:                </tr>
   ....:                </tbody>
   ....:        </table""")

In [15]: selector.xpath('//table/tr')
Out[15]: []

In [16]: selector.xpath('//table//tr')
Out[16]: 
[<Selector xpath='//table//tr' data=u'<tr><td class="postac">Zinacef </td>\n\t\t<'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//tr' data=u'<tr><td class="postac">Zinacef </td>\n\t\t<'>]

In [17]: for row in selector.xpath('//table//tr'):
   ....:     print row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()
   ....:     
[u'proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu ', u'i.v.', u'\n                            1,5 g\n                        1 fiol. typu Monovial\n        ']
[u'proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu ', u'i.v.', u'\n                            750 mg\n                        1 fiol. typu Monovial\n        ']

In [18]: [u''.join(row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()) for row in selector.xpath('//table//tr')]
Out[18]: 
[u'proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu i.v.\n                            1,5 g\n                        1 fiol. typu Monovial\n        ',
 u'proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu i.v.\n                            750 mg\n                        1 fiol. typu Monovial\n        ']

In [19]:
```

Comment: Looks like things are getting more complicated here [link](http://bazalekow.mp.pl/leki/item.html?id=28611&item_id=80119) Could you take a look please? There is a second internal table which interferes with extracting the correct data. I did this: [u''.join(row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()) for row in sel.xpath('//table[not(ancestor::div)]//tr')] but it doesn't work

Comment: you can use `[u''.join(row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()) for row in selector.xpath('//table[@class="table-postaci"]/tbody/tr')]` or maybe easier with CSS selectors: `[u''.join(row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()) for row in selector.css('table.table-postaci > tr, table.table-postaci > tbody > tr')]` (which accounts for `tr` in `tbody` or not

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid /text() for exactly this reason. Usually you don't want the individual text nodes, you want the string value of the element, which you can get with the string() function. It's not clear what programming language you are calling XPath from, or whether it's XPath 1.0 or 2.0 - that will affect the detail, e.g. whether to get the string value of the element in the XPath expression or in the host language.

Comment: Thank you for help. I'm afraid Scrapy doesn't support Xpath 2.0, so I made a pipeline function to strip html tags.

Answer (score 1):

The `td` node in your question has three child nodes – first a text node with the contents:

```
proszek do sporz. roztworu do wlewu
```

second an `I` element node that has its own child text node, and last another text node with the contents:

```
\n                    1,5 g\n                1 fiol. typu Monovial\n
```

Your query, the end of which looks like `td[2]/text()`, only selects the immediate text node children of the `td` element, so it doesn’t select the `I` element node or its text node child. The result is the two text nodes that you are seeing.

You could select *all* text node decedents of the `td` element using `td[2]//text()` (note the double slash `//`). This will return *three* text nodes in the result – the two as above and a third containing `i.v.` in between them. You could then join them outside XPath (I’m not familiar with scrapy so I can’t tell you how to that in this case).

As far as I know you can’t join the three nodes directly using XPath 1.0, but it might be possible with XPath 2.0.

Comment: Thank you for enlightenment! I still have a problem with joining the string. Seems that scrapy doesn't support xpath 2.0 and joining in the pipeline is a problem, because some tables contain more than one row so the function would have to know where to stop and then start joining another row.